# connect button to label - python & Qt4 designer

Tags: python, qt4

Im just starting out making GUI applications and Im writing a hangman game in python

What I cant figure out is how to connect button clicks to stuff other than just clear() (in the code there is a section that reads self.label.clear) but I'd like to for example make the text label display 'a' if I clicked the button or run a function
I have had the button run a function but the results only show up on the terminal

How can I make the label read 'a' by clicking the button?

Also, Is Qt4 designer regarded as a 'bad' GUI program? All results to questions  I've googled regarding python and GUI seem to have a code not that similar to the code generated from Qt4?

Here is the code freshly generated from Qt4, before I butchered it for hours

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig,_encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.Button = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 180, 85, 27))
        self.Button.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Button"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 50, 58, 15))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.Button, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.label.clear)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.Button.setText(_translate("Form", "a", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "okaiokai", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a new method to receive clicked and process.

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.Button = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 180, 85, 27))
        self.Button.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Button"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 50, 58, 15))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.Button, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.setLabel)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def setLabel(self):
        self.label.setText(self.Button.text())
```